# Extract columns with range in Google Colab

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory, multiple-columns

I want to extract some columns maybe just 10 from a datafram with 30 columns but I'm not finding any code or functions to do it, I tried with iloc but not good results at all, help please here is my data frame:

So I just want to get the columns 1 to 10:
df1_10 = df.columns['1'....'10']
[image]

Comment: `df.iloc[:, 1:11]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch 10 columns from your dataset then use this piece of code

```
df.iloc[:,1:11] # this will give you 10 columns


df.iloc[:,1:10] # this will give you only 9 columns.
                # This is what you use in your code that's why you don't get the desired result.
```